# How to create a sorted Array who's order is associated to an input

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

Essentially I have a function that calculates the average weighted score of person. If one of the inputs is name, ex name = "John Smith" and their final grade is total = 100. If I were to run this program again for a different person and their name = "Bob Joe" and total = 95 and store each of these. How would I associate the numbers to the name so that there would be an ascending array of names based on their total scores.

My expected results are

namesOrder = [100,95,81,55]

gradesOrder = [John Smith, Bob Joe, Billy Kid, Dum Dum]

grades organized in order of score received

Comment: You can use a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do that.

The first, and probably clearest, is to use a `list` of `dicts` and sort by the *score* key:

```
from operator import itemgetter

unsorted_data = [{'name': 'John Smith', 'score': 100},
                 {'name': 'Dum Dum', 'score': 55},
                 {'name': 'Billy Kid', 'score': 81},
                 {'name': 'Bob Joe', 'score': 95}]

sorted(unsorted_data, key=itemgetter('score'))
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'Dum Dum', 'score': 55}, {'name': 'Billy Kid', 'score': 81}, {'name': 'Bob Joe', 'score': 95}, {'name': 'John Smith', 'score': 100}]
```

The second is to use a single `dict`:

```
scores = {'John Smith': 100, 'Bob Joe': 95, 'Billy Kid': 81, 'Dum Dum': 55}

sorted(scores.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
```

Output:

```
[('Dum Dum', 55), ('Billy Kid', 81), ('Bob Joe', 95), ('John Smith', 100)]
```

This is, IMO, less intuitive, since it returns a `list` of `tuples` that you have to index by position, rather than an obvious string key. It saves a little space, but this is the kind of thing that you should almost never worry about optimising, since you're using Python anyway.

The last is to sort based on `zip`:

```
namesOrder = [100, 95, 81, 55]
gradesOrder = ['John Smith', 'Bob Joe', 'Billy Kid', 'Dum Dum']

[name for grade, name in sorted(zip(namesOrder, gradesOrder))]
```

Output:

```
['Dum Dum', 'Billy Kid', 'Bob Joe', 'John Smith']
```

This returns *only* the names, which might be what you want in some situations, and doesn't require you to create an intermediate data structure if your data comes in multiple `lists`.

You can also pass `reverse=True` to any of the `sorted` calls to sort in descending order, instead of the default ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code of how I would do this (this took me a while):

```
grades = {}


def ordered_score():
    gradesOrder = []
    namesOrder = []
    for a in sorted(list(grades.values()), reverse=True):
        gradesOrder.append(a)
    for a in gradesOrder:
        for b, c in sorted(list(grades.items())):
            if a == c:
                namesOrder.append(b)
    return gradesOrder, namesOrder


grades['Jacob'] = 52
grades['Elsa'] = 97
grades['Timber'] = 22

new_grades = ordered_score()

print(ordered_score()[0])
print(ordered_score()[1])
```

The printed results look like this:

```
[97, 52, 22]
['Elsa', 'Jacob', 'Timber']
```